# Copy only .nki files from multiple folders (keeping folder structure) and replace copied files by shortcuts to the original files

Tags: windows, command-line, copy-paste, shortcut

In Windows, How can I Copy only .nki files from multiple folders (keeping folder structure) and then replace all copied files inside newly created folders by shortcuts to the original files ?

Is that possible ? I'm looking to do that in one go with a command line or a script. Thanks !

I tried Fastcopy from multiple sources with "*.nki" as an include filter, but I only want to create shortcuts to the original files not copy the files themselves.